# Set expansion in a hypercube

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let there be a $n-$dim hypercube $Q_n(V,E)$ graph where $V$ is the set of vertices. Let $A\subset V$ with $|A|=m$. Let $E(A)$ be the set of neighboring vertices of vertices in $A$ s.t. $E(A)$ does not include the vertices of $A$. I am trying to find $m$ s.t. $\frac{|E(A)|}{|A|}$ is minimum i.e.:

> Find $$\arg \min_A \frac{|E(A)|}{|A|}$$

If $|A|=1$, then $\frac{|E(A)|}{|A|}=n$ which I believe is the maximum value for $\frac{|E(A)|}{|A|}$ and when $|A|=\frac{2^n}{2}$ i.e. $A$ has half the vertices of $V$, then $\frac{|E(A)|}{|A|}=1$. So I am thinking the minimum of $\frac{|E(A)|}{|A|}$ is attained for $m=\frac{2^n}{4}$ or something like that so that $\frac{|E(A)|}{|A|}=O(\frac{n}{2^n})$ because each vertex in $A$ has about $n$ neighbors.

The hypercube is bipartite. Any suggestions on how to approach this problem?

Comment: In most cases, $|E(A)|$ is going to be dependent on *which* vectors are in $A$, and not only on the size of $A$. Are you thinking of the average? Or just the minimum possible over all sets of a particular size?

Comment: For example if $|A|=2$, then $|E(A)|$ will be different depending on whether the two vertices in $A$ are adjacent or not.

Comment: If $n=3$ and $A=\{000,100,010,001\}$, $E(A)=\{011,101,110\}$, and you get a ratio of only $\frac34$.

Comment: @MorganRodgers True, thinking of minimum possible over all sets of a particular size. Yes, the minimum would be when vertices are adjacent.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I see, true, I am wrong then.

Comment: Does $E(A)$ include neighbours that lie in $A$? If yes, then @BrianM.Scott 's example should include all of $A$ in $E(A)$.

Comment: @stackex33 It doesn't, sorry I should've stated that in the question. editing it now.